# Keep laptop ON sometimes

Tags: 16.04

Is a script/program to keep my laptop ON, preventing it to go into sleep/hibernate mode, sometimes?

I do not want to changed the settings, because only sometimes I want it to stay awake, and other times I want to get it into sleep/hibernate mode.

Note: setting it to never go into hibernat/sleep mode and when leaving to press `command + l` is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`caffeine` is available in the default repositories.

Quoting from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/caffeine)

> A status bar application able to temporarily prevent the activation of
>   both the screensaver and the "sleep" powersaving mode.

Install via

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install caffeine
```